# Correctly formatting automatic APA 7th edition style citations in Word

Tags: publications, citations, citation-style

I have Office 365 and in Microsoft Word which is updated to the latest edition. I could manually enter inline citations, but for speed and ease of citing, I have elected to use the automatic citation generator.

I need to cite in the APA 7th edition style. However, I have noticed that when using the automatic citation generator, the correct APA citation is not provided in a couple of situations; and maybe more issues may come to light as I move forward.

One situation is that when, let's say you have a citation with say 4 authors, the inline citation will mention all 4 authors followed by the year, when it should mention the first author surname followed by *et al.*

For example, Word will cite

> (Okami, Olmstead, Abramson, & Pendleton, 1998)

[when it should be](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/11/the-proper-use-of-et-al-in-apa-style.html)

> (Okami et al., 1998)

There is also a [known bug](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apa-mla-chicago-%E2%80%93-automatically-format-bibliographies-405c207c-7070-42fa-91e7-eaf064b14dbb) where if you have multiple citations from the same author, the citation generator fills in the publication title when it's not supposed to.

The Microsoft website provides a workaround for the meantime on the incorrect addition of the publication title, but has not been very helpful in dealing with other issues.

It says on the link above

> **Important:** APA and MLA can change their formats, so you’ll want to ensure that these format versions meet your requirements. You can create your own updated version of a style or build custom styles. For more information see [Bibliography & Citations 102 – Building Custom styles](https://blogs.office.com/2009/04/29/bibliography-citations-102-building-custom-styles/).

but the link is dead.

Is there a more reliable style I can download and use in Word?  If not, how can I edit the current APA style to correct the issues or create a custom version?

Comment: I voted to close because questions about bugs in software are not questions about academia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instructions on building your own custom citation style can be found at [this Microsoft webpage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/objects-properties-methods/create-custom-bibliography-styles).  This instruction can be used to learn how to modify the current style, or use it as a template for a separate corrected style.

In the meantime, whilst working on the style, I found a workaround for the *et al.* inline citations [in SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/779142/581166).  You may manually edit incorrect inline citations by editing the field.  Doing this is still quicker than manually typing all citations and references as it only affects a few inline citations.

For example, with the inline citation used in the question

> (Okami, Olmstead, Abramson, & Pendleton, 1998)

right click on the citation and select the "Edit Field" option.

The citation field for this example was:

`CITATION Oka98 \l 2057`

If you edit it to this:

`CITATION Oka98 \n  \t  \l 2057  \f "Okami et al., "`

It becomes:

> (Okami et al., 1998)

The following explains the switches used.

`\n` removes the author names

`\t` removes the title (to prevent it being displayed with the other bug)

`\l` is for the locale code

`\f` is for a prefix which in this case replaces the author names.

Comment: I do understand that the question pertains to APA 6th edition. However, anyone viewing this thread may want to take note of a change in the recently released 7th edition: Any citations with three or more authors are now cited as "et al."  beginning with the first citation. (Hallelujah!)

Comment: @RJo - You pointed out an error in my question. I was actually referring to 7th edition.